# How to classify the queries or mutations to different types of GraphQL in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

I try to implement GraphQL with NestJS as [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start). But I cannot find a better way to organize these queries or mutations. If I create hundreds of queries, I would classify them to the different types. But I cannot do it in "Code First" or "Schema First" way.

For example(Schema First), for MovieMutation collects all mutations relating to the Movie. The following `schema.graphql` is not working and it throws the error `defined in resolvers, but not in schema`.

```
type Mutation {
  MovieMutation: MovieMutation
}

type MovieMutation {
  """Add a movie to the DynamoDB."""
  addMovie(input: MovieInput!): Movie!

  """Delete a movie from the DynamoDB."""
  deleteMovie(id: String!): Movie!
}
```

Is it possible to classify queries or mutations to different types as I mentioned above in "Code First" and "Schema First"?